# How to fit a sine wave to a small set of data in Python?

Tags: python, data-analysis, physics, curve-fitting

Ive been struggling to create a proper sine wave (whos parameters will be used later for a type of analysis similar to angstroms method). This is the closest I've gotten. Mathematica is able to create the correct wave with little to no issues. It seems the problem is that the amplitude is too high for scipy to recognize it as part of the wave, I tried to solve this problem by normalizing (as seen below) but it does not change anything.

Blue is what python finds and red is what it should be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOhuz.png

Here is the scratch code ive been playing with, there are two y lists because I need to compare both waves to find amplitude and phase differences but right now, I just need the sine fit to work:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing



def normalize(list):
    scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (-1,1))
    r_list = list.reshape(-1,1)
    nrlist = scaler.fit_transform(r_list)
    nlist = nrlist.reshape(-1,)
    print(nlist)
    return nlist



x_data = np.array([0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345, 360, 375, 390])

#y_data = np.array([213.81356073047021, 218.49141430729355, 208.71044773757197, 204.4578535768235, 213.38830131439533, 218.06615489121873, 208.28518832149715, 204.4578535768235, 213.38830131439533, 218.91667372336838, 209.98622598579655, 207.43466948934744, 215.51459839476962, 219.34193313944326, 209.56096656972167, 205.73363182504804, 213.81356073047021, 219.34193313944326, 209.13570715364685, 205.73363182504804, 214.23882014654504, 219.76719255551808, 209.98622598579655, 206.58415065719774, 216.79037664299415, 220.61771138766778, 210.83674481794628])

y_data = np.array([215.66887756527237, 220.27067278975787, 210.6487373203791, 206.46528711630134, 215.25053254486457, 219.85232776935007, 210.2303922999713, 206.46528711630134, 215.25053254486457, 220.6890178101656, 211.9037723816024, 209.39370225915576, 217.34225764690348, 221.1073628305734, 211.4854273611946, 207.72032217752465, 215.66887756527237, 221.1073628305734, 211.06708234078684, 207.72032217752465, 216.0872225856801, 221.52570785098118, 211.9037723816024, 208.5570122183402, 218.59729270812676, 222.36239789179672, 212.74046242241795])

print(y_data)
nylist = normalize(y_data)

def test_func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.sin(b * x)

params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, nylist,
                                               p0=[2, 2])

print(params)


plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(x_data, nylist, label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, test_func(x_data, params[0], params[1]),
         label='Fitted function')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated, I've been stuck for quite some time and every example I try to work with does not work with my set of data for some reason and as im somewhat new to python there are likely things im missing.

Thanks again!

Comment: Add a parameter for phase -- `f = a * np.sin(b * x + c)`.

Comment: and ditch the `normalize` stuff  in exchange for an overall offset. Put good starting values. `b = 0.1` seems more likely

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the data it doesn't start at (0,0), which means
a plain sin function won't work. You'll need an offset and can skip
the normalize.

```
def test_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.sin(b * x) + c

params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data,
                                               p0=[2, 0.1, 215.67])
```

A suggestion from me is also to use a linspace instead of the x_data
for the plot.

```
x = np.linspace(x_data[0],x_data[-1],200)
plt.plot(x, test_func(x, *params),
         label='Fitted function')
print(*params)
```

Leading to this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKgh4.png)